# pgadmin-4 in docker failed with gunicorn server start error

Tags: docker, pgadmin-4

I am trying to run pgadmin in docker like below and getting exception while starting gunicorn 20.0.4 error. Any pointers to fix this?

```
docker run -p 80:80  -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=email@domain.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres" -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

Docker logs

```
NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.
[2021-08-13 03:03:04 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-08-13 03:03:04 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-08-13 03:03:05 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-08-13 03:03:06 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-08-13 03:03:07 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-08-13 03:03:08 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2021-08-13 03:03:09 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('::', 80)
```

Comment: Do you already have something listening on port 80 on your host?

Comment: No, nothing is listening in port 80

Answer (score 14):

I guess you are working on a **IPv6-disabled systems**, from the `/entrypoint.sh`, the gunicorn command is next:

```
exec /venv/bin/gunicorn --timeout ${TIMEOUT} --bind ${PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS:-[::]}:${PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT:-80} -w 1 --threads ${GUNICORN_THREADS:-25} --access-logfile ${GUNICORN_ACCESS_LOGFILE:--} -c gunicorn_config.py run_pgadmin:app
```

This means it's default use ipv6 address, so I think you may have a trial with gunicorn listen on ipv4 address by pass **`PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0`** to run command:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -e "PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=email@domain.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres" -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

Comment: this worked for me and I have ipv6 disabled, thanks!

Comment: Does not work for me on a Synology NAS, downgrading to pgadmin 4.8 solved the issue

Comment: Solved by putting another listening port than 80, `PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 8000` as pointed in the doc: *On some filesystems that do not support extended attributes, it may not be possible to run pgAdmin without specifying a value for PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT that is greater than 1024.*